# Dynamically increase a base integer value up to a max according to range?

Tags: python

Playing around with Python what I'm trying to achieve is, given a range and a base int value, return a float value which is closer than a peak value the closer it is to the end of the range, i.e.

```
base_value = 1
peak_value = 2
range = range(4, 8)

compute_value(value): ... # return value according to range and base/peak values.

compute_value(4): result = 1
compute_value(5): result = 1.2
compute_value(6): result = 1.8
compute_value(8): result = 2
```

Is there any built-in func which may perform this or a mathematical function with a similar behaviour?

Comment: `range` is an integer sequence type, not an interval, by the way - it's not a good fit for representing what you're trying to represent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = [2, 4]
y = [4, 8]
query = 3
print(np.interp(3, x, y))
```

x is your base and peak, y is your range
and, query is the point between base and peak

It's actually simple linear interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

```py
base_value = 1
peak_value = 2
my_range = range(4, 8)


def compute_value(value):
    return_val = value * (peak_value - base_value) / \
        (my_range[-1] + 1 - my_range[0])
    print(return_val)


compute_value(4)
compute_value(5)
compute_value(6)
compute_value(8)
```

the output:

```
1.0
1.25
1.5
2.0
```